# sbt published maven file missing artifacts with multiple scopes

Tags: maven, sbt

Say I have a project `B` that depends on project `A` with `test->test` and `provided` scopes.

```
val B = Project(
  id = "project-B",
  base = file("myproject"),
).dependsOn(A % "test->test;provided")
```

The published maven pom file for `B`, however, only has the test dependency.

Why is the `provided` dependency left out ?

**Update**:

This is the actual SBT codes in [our project](https://github.com/apache/incubator-gearpump/blob/master/project/BuildGearpump.scala)

```
lazy val streaming = Project(
id = "gearpump-streaming",
base = file("streaming"),
settings = commonSettings ++ myAssemblySettings ++ javadocSettings ++
  addArtifact(Artifact("gearpump-streaming"), sbtassembly.AssemblyKeys.assembly) ++
  Seq(
    assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
      case "geardefault.conf" =>
        MergeStrategy.last
      case x =>
        val oldStrategy = (assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly).value
        oldStrategy(x)
    },

    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "com.goldmansachs" % "gs-collections" % gsCollectionsVersion
    ),

    pomPostProcess := {
      (node: xml.Node) => changeShadedDeps(
        Set(
          "com.goldmansachs",
          "org.scala-lang",
          "org.scoverage"
        ),
        List(
          getShadedDepXML(organization.value, s"${core.id}_${scalaBinaryVersion.value}",
            version.value, "provided")),
        node)
    }
  )
).dependsOn(core % "test->test;provided")
```

The `pomPostProcess` is to remove unwanted dependencies from the published pom file and add `core` dependency with `provided` scope.

Without the latter, the pom file would be like

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.apache.gearpump</groupId>
<artifactId>gearpump-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<description>gearpump-streaming</description>
<version>0.8.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>gearpump-streaming</name>
<organization>
    <name>org.apache.gearpump</name>
</organization>
<url>https://github.com/apache/incubator-gearpump</url>
<licenses>
    <license>
        <name>Apache 2</name>
        <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt</url>
    </license>
</licenses>
<scm>
    <connection>scm:git://git.apache.org/incubator-gearpump.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:apache/incubator-gearpump</developerConnection>
    <url>github.com/apache/incubator-gearpump</url>
</scm>
<developers>
    <developer>
        <id>gearpump</id>
        <name>Gearpump Team</name>
        <url>http://gearpump.incubator.apache.org/community.html#who-we-are</url>
    </developer>
</developers>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.gearpump</groupId>
        <artifactId>gearpump-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

You can see that the "provided" dependency is left out.

Comment: As far as I know, Maven POMs cannot have dependencies with multiple scopes. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to have two dependencies of project `A`, one with scope `provided`, the other `test`.

Comment: Those dependencies will probably override each other. But: provided dependencies are also available on the test classpath. So you don't need to have a test entry if you have a provided entry.

Comment: I get compile error if removing the test entry. I think it's legit to have two dependencies of the same project with two scopes in Maven.

Comment: Then please show us the pom file and the compile error.

Comment: @jf-meier added  more details

Comment: I'm sorry that I don't understand the sbt part. But to get a clean pom I would only add the dependency as provided (and not as test). If you do this and get any error, could you please show that particular error?

Comment: @jf-meier The pom file is generated by `sbt publish` and my problem is that somehow the `provided` dependency gets lost.

Comment: Leave out the test dependency, use only the provided one. Then everything will probably work fine.

Comment: That will cause compile failure for tests in `gearpump-streaming` project